# How do I create a subdomain for a site hosted by someone who does not allow it?

Tags: web-hosting, subdomain, nameserver

I want to create a subdomain for a site hosted by Jimdo (a DIY website builder).

Jimdo does not allow subdomains however. I am trying to find a workaround where a subdomain is hosted elsewhere but everything else remains as it is. E.g. I use their email service and I want to keep it.

The domain is not hosted by Jimdo, but by a host that allows me to edit my zones.
It points to the Jimdo NS.

I have independent hosting where I have NS information. This is where I want to host my subdomain.

My thinking was that I could use ZoneEdit as a "fork" that allows me to keep using my Jimdo page like before and, at the same time, directs a subdomain to another host. Provided this is possible:

**Question:**
How do I configure ZoneEdit CNAME or NS records to forward visitors to my website and my email to my Jimdo mail account while pointing a subdomain to another host?

Comment: This may seem obvious but I've been searching online for quite some time and I can't seem to find an answer that is easy to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this can only be pulled off reliably if I have the A records of my website. If my website host does not provide A records information, there is no guarantee that the A records of your website won't change.
Once that happens, **your website will no longer be on line**.

You would have to use a website monitoring tool that informs you as soon as your site is down to have some sort of insurance that you will be notified when the IP address – that is the A records – of your website changes.

So the solution works, but only at your own risk.

I have chosen not to run that risk and will find some other solution than a subdomain.

Comment: If anyone disagrees, please do let me know. I'm willing to reedit my question and my answer to accommodate better solutions. And if you like my answer, don't hesitate to vote me up :-)